# Trouble finishing the Login/Register Router with Express.js via HTTP req/res

Tags: node.js, authentication, http-post, httprequest, httpresponse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZSO5.png)So I'm trying to set up the login/register routers for users via middleware functions and POST method through HTTP request/respond, but I'm having trouble finishing up the routers for both. I created both '200' and '401' status codes in the login route, but just trying to figure out how to do this for the register user router.

This was coded in Express.js on VS Code. PS I got the Port listening on 3060, and when I type in localhost:3060, I get Cannot Get 404 error code on the Chrome browser. I don't have any specific syntax errors in my app.js module.

I even tried reading through the documents on express.com and MDN, but didn't find any solutions. I know this can't be that difficult, because eventually I want to implement logout route and
email
regex and hashed passwords eventually. But anyway here is the code for both app.js and package.json

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql')

const port = 3060;

// Connect to MySQL database
const sqlconn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    email: "coreyjames689@aol.com",
    password: "dsfsd78df&I*\$",
    name: "Corey James",
    database: "MyDB",
    port: 3020
});

sqlconn.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database connection successful");
});

//Router for user registering an account with middleware
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    
    res.status(200).send('Successfully created an account')

});

// Router (API) for login in Express.js using HTTP Req & Res (POST)
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    const email = 'example@email.com'
    const password = 'Password123!'
    
    if(!email) res.status(401).send('Invalid email')
    if(!password) res.status(401).send('Invalid password')
    res.status(200).send('Successful login')
});

// Router for logging out user
app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Successfully logged out')
    
});

// server is listening on port 3060
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}..`);
})

{
  "dependencies": {
    "email-regex": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3"
  },
  "name": "projectvirtual",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "startdev": "env-cmd -e dev nodemon server.js",
    "startprod": "env-cmd -e prod nodemon server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

I tried going over the code for app.js, there are no syntax problems that I'm aware of. I'm not sure if I'm getting this error code on the browser because I'm using POST for both routers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZSO5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EbnE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QqEF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvVxH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArhsY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set up route `app.get('/')` or `app.get('/login')`, that's why you get `404` error when visitting `localhost:3060`.

For the login route you should not send the response immediately but only check the email and password:

```
if(!email) res.status(401).send('invalid email')
if(!password) res.status(401).send('invalid password')
res.status(200).send('login success')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I just don't like using ChatGPT. Many people tend to use the platform as a crutch. PS I'm assuming that the HTTP method for the logout route would be DELETE, since the user is logging out.

Comment: So I revised the source code and pasted this change in the original post. I believe it looks a lot cleaner, albeit shorter. Please let me know what you think

Comment: @Cordev87 It's pretty ok now, the only thing left is the `next` in your controller. Only put `err` and `next` in middleware so your colleague can understand your code better. Middleware and controller are just functions that work with request and response, but middleware always runs before controller and middleware uses `err` to handle error, `next` to end the middleware and run the controller. This is the concept/convention that pretty much all backend frameworks use.

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with err thank you, just not sure how to implement it in my routes for login. As far as colleague, I am the solo developer for this project. I would like to find another technical cofounder eventually, once I get better with Express.js/Node.js. But for now, it's all on me. I plan to finish the project next year. But I should use DELETE for logout route correct?

Comment: @Cordev87 Generally most people would use `POST` for log out, but it's fine if you want to use `DELETE`. REST Api is just a architectural style, it's not a must, you can set the method how you see fit. But don't use `GET` for log out though because browser might pre-fetch a page with it.

Comment: @Cordev87 actually on second thought you should just follow the most general approach. Different method in different framework might exposed to security vulnerability, so sticking with what most people have agreed is the best. `POST` for both log in and log out because request body can be encripted to be secured.

Comment: Yeah, I'd never use GET for sign out route. I guess it doesn't matter to me which one I choose. I've just read through different resources online that it's best practice to use DELETE. As far as 'err', I think I see what you mean, I know how to get it started, i.e. app.post('/'(err, req, res) => {}). Then would be console.log(err) or something like thrown in there, not too experience as far as this. Lastly, the only other thing to do for now is to maybe work on the middleware for the register route, that email regex and hashed passwords.

Comment: @Cordev87 `DELETE` method doesn't have request body just like `GET`, so be careful handling data if you really want to use it for log out. Anyway, are you making middleware for only register route? Generally we make middleware if it's used for 2 or more routes.

Comment: Yes, login and register routes. But I also am going to add other routes for two different profile pages, a profile for job seeker and another for the company. Once I finish the backend/frontend for the login/profile screens. I will get started on the messenger (chat) feature using sockets. Basically, my project is a marketplace/professional networking specifically designed for work from home jobs. I was simply asking if the next middleware for the register would be to authenticate the email/password using encryption techniques. But the JWT course will get into that

Comment: @Cordev87 I don't think JWT handle encryption. JWT is for authorization, not authentication. You will need regex for email validation and libraries for hash like bcrypt. Don't worry they are very easy to implement, basically just copy paste. For sockets it will be very complicated at first but eventually you will realize it's just about creating an event and define what to do when said event is triggered.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But I would soon need to add password reset link and email confirmation to the login route soon. The JWT video covers that as well

Comment: By the way, are you familiar with PostgreSLQ, specifically connecting it to VS Code?

Comment: @Cordev87 No, i only work with sql server, mysql and mongodb. By connecting do you mean connect with your backend or the IDE for visualized tables?

Comment: Yeah I suppose. I already have PostgreSQL installed on my OS. But it keeps giving me an error in the terminal output. Not sure if you're familiar with VS Code or not. The instructor is using MongoDB as well, but I'd rather PostgreSQL. In the database, it's connected on a different Port, so not sure if that's why it's doing this

Comment: I'm also taking a PostgreSQL course, to better understand it

Comment: Maybe I should ask another question on here regarding this issue. I've tried Googling the solution, with no luck.

Comment: I decided to use MySQL to see how it does. The problem is, I'm not able to connect to the DB via VS Code/Express.js. When I run the command 'node server.js in the terminal I get this error 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client'. Other suggestions I've tried are ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password' which case I got this error ALTER: Command not found. I don't think there's anything wrong with my code in server.js, I'll revise the code in the original post for you to see

Comment: Please I've tried everything, I even closed VS Code and uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL

Comment: @Cordev87 ALTER is a query, did you type it in cmd? If you did then try again in workbench and see what happens. Anyway i suggest using typeORM package to connect to db since you can change to postgre or whatever later with it. mysql last publish is 4 years ago while typeORM's is 10 hours ago.

Comment: [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm) is the TypeORM package. It can be a bit annoying at first but very convenient once you get a hold of it. Read the docs carefully they explain thoroughly how to use it.

Comment: The docs is for typescript, but you can use the package for js like normal.

Comment: Not sure about workbench, I did type this query in the terminal though. Are you saying that MySQL is outdated for database setup?

Comment: Actually I tweaked a few things in my base code. I will paste it shortly here. I get a different error since I used a different port number for my database. I will try and upload the screenshot of the error in my cmd.

Comment: I know MySQL can't be this difficult to integrate into my backend, at least not as difficult as other things I will do for my project in the near future. I'm still on that JWT tutorial, and although he's using Mongoose, I still want to use MySQL because of issues that I've had with that db

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I'm using a MacOS

Comment: @Cordev87 MySQL Workbench is a tool for database design, you can directly type query into it. If you still wanna use command prompt only then you can log in first with `mysql -u root -p` (replace root with your username), then enter your password. Now you can write query into the command prompt instead of doing so on workbench.

Comment: Yeah I believe I tried 'mysql -u root -p' and mysql wasn't found. How do I workbench again?

Comment: 'zsh: command not found: mysql' is what I got particularly

Comment: This just doesn't make sense since I do have the latest version of MySQL installed

Comment: @Cordev87 I didn't see that you're using Mac by the time i wrote the reply. If you use Mac then you have to navigate to the `bin` folder of mysql: `cd /mysql/bin/`. Change the command to your exact path in your pc. Then you can type the query by `./mysql -u root -p -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';"`

Comment: Actually just install MySQL workbench, it's a great tool to visualize the tables from database. It's equivalent to MongoDB Compass, as most database have this type of tool. How do you view the data from your mysql database? Through VSC?

Comment: I got this error this time 'cd: no such file or directory: /mysql/bin/'. But I believe that this is the correct PATH to MySQL. I got it from my Mac settings: '/usr/local/mysql-8.2.0-macos13-arm64'.

Comment: I guess via VSCode. I would like to view the database outside my IDE though.

Comment: @Cordev87 change the command to `cd /usr/local/mysql-8.2.0-macos13-arm64/bin` and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay, this didn't show any errors, now what should I type?

Comment: Should I type 'node server.js. This is the entry file

Comment: @Cordev87 No, type `./mysql -u root -p -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"` as you wanna change your password and privilege to use `mysql` package. Remember to replace your actual password into the command.

Comment: Try the command without `@'localhost'` too if the first one doesn't work.

Comment: You said replace my actual password. What password are you talking about? Are you referring to the password for my OS?

Comment: Now it says dqoute>

Comment: @Cordev87 replace the 'password' to whatever the password you set for the user in mysql. I can see it's 'dsfsd78df&I*\$' in your code.

Comment: If there is no error then you can run your express server

Comment: Okay I put that password in, now all it shows is dqoute> repeatedly in the cmd

Comment: I don't see any errors in the cmd

Comment: @Cordev87 then run your server and see if it's good or not. If it doesn't work i say we should change to `TypeORM` package instead, it's regulary updated.

Comment: So 'node server.js' then?

Comment: No, still doesn't run. It might be possible that I have some kind of bug or something

Comment: @Cordev87 what's the error when you run the server?

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't working, why it still can't connect. I did everything right on my end

Comment: Basically the same error that you see in the screenshot I sent in my OP

Comment: You put the image in the code block, i can't see it. put it out of the code block ```   ````. The format of the link is [text](link)

Comment: Sorry I'll fix that now

Comment: Please try and check the image now

Comment: Is the screenshot visible now?

Comment: @Cordev87 try changing localhost to your mysql server ip then. If i remember correctly localhost can only be used on window.

Comment: Well I mean I do technically have my own server running on localhost, the same same server you were helping me out with a few days ago. By MySQL server do you mean, 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Localhost can only be used on Windows. Is that only for SQL database purposes?

Comment: @Cordev87 Back when i learned about connecting to mysql with express i was taught that i should use 'localhost' in connect string on window only. And yes, ip of mysql server is 127.0.0.1. The error you got is simply wrong connect string, so mysql server refused the connection.

Comment: If it doesn't work you can try your system IP address too.

Comment: Type ipconfig to cmd and find your IPv4 address

Comment: Yes, it makes it much more annoying when you have a MacOS instead of Windows. I'll try the local IP on my system instead. Would it be iPv4 or iPv6 or does it matter?

Comment: No, I tried the iPv4 route, still not getting a connection

Comment: @Cordev87 Can you check the username, database name and the port in `createConnection`? Take a screenshot.

Comment: Okay I will, this is frustrating though. I'm clearly doing everything right, there's no reason why I shouldn't be able to secure a connection to the db

Comment: I took another screenshot with the highlighted block of the code. Let me know what you think

Comment: I screenshotted another section of the error message in the cmd

Comment: @Cordev87 i mean the setting of your mysql instance. Did you explicity change the port of mysql? need to make sure that we have the right information and privilege to connect. MySQL workbench is recommeneded to check these things, but we still can manage through system command line if needed.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't even remember seeing that option. Do they have to have separate ports? I'm still trying to figure how to open the settings

Comment: Also what does MySQL workbench actually do? I've heard of it, never used it

Comment: @Cordev87 MySQL workbench is basically an app that helps you design your database with visualized tables, command, export/import/migrate data easier by simply clicking buttons instead of typing tons of commands. If you don't explicitly change mysql port then it will use the default which is `3306`. Change it in your `mysql.createConnection`

Comment: I tried this default Port and still wouldn't work. I uploaded another screenshot of the new error message

Comment: so your server does run on port 3306, the problem is the user that you're trying to use doesn't have the privilege to connect. Did you change your username in the mysql server? if not you should use "root". You can remove the email and port, they are not needed anymore. Also make sure that the database you're trying to connect was already created

Comment: Okay, but why remove email? I intend to store email addresses in the database.

Comment: Same error, I'll screenshot the code. I think it's the DB I created. Anyway, I'll screenshot the revised mysql.createConnection

Comment: That is not how you store the email to database though. You have to insert the data to a table. Anyway, change the host to the default one which is 127.0.0.1

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about that, my bad

Comment: I changed it and got this:    '  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true'

Comment: Strange, every time I click 'node server.js', I keep getting a popup message from my OS but then it closes immediately. I believe one of the options is to connect.

Comment: type this into your system command line `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` and find the ip that has port 3306 attached to it. It's the ip of mysql server.

Comment: I uploaded another screenshot of the error I got when I typed this.

Comment: Nevermind stupid SO is giving me problems. Here is what I get 'latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
coreyvigil@Coreys-Air ProjectVirtual % '

Comment: try `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` instead then.

Comment: actually try `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep mysql`, it should filter the ones that contain the word 'mysql'.

Comment: I got this 'mysqld    49225         _mysql   18u  IPv6 0xd308fb3968d17de7      0t0    TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)
mysqld    49225         _mysql   21u  IPv6 0xd308fb39694195e7      0t0    TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)'. Maybe I should use iPv6 instead of the other IP's

Comment: It did filter these out, however. It just shows the mysql and Ports specified

Comment: What am I looking for again?

Comment: It spits out '49225', not sure what this number means.

Comment: no, the * means it's listening on all available IP, so we can use the default `127.0.0.1:3306`. Now the only things we need left is the username and password. the default name is root, try it and see what we have.

Comment: So I tried this and it did let me click on 'Allow' on the popup that keeps showing up. But still can't connect

Comment: @Cordev87 what's written on the pop up? anyway i think we should move the conversation to somewhere that we can share the screenshots easier, like discord or steam or whatever. we're gonna see to the end of this road. this is the most basic step of making a server, we will not stuck here.

Comment: That's what I'm insinuating. This shouldn't be this hard, the MySQL setup. Anyway Discord is fine.

Comment: It asks me if I want to allow a connection or something. The choices are Allow and Deny. But this is based on MacOS

Comment: i actually don't use discord often so i might not know the way around lol. can we direct message without being on friendlist? my username is 'freegwid', it's random so there should be only one. anyway, i never got a pop up for allowing connection before so it's a bit strange. maybe you can change to `mysql2` package, it has the same syntax as the older `mysql` package

Comment: Yeah I've heard of mysql12, I can try that. How does it work, I just uninstall my current package $ install the other afterwards. Yeah it's possible I may bugs or something

Comment: That's fine, we can try that

Comment: `npm uninstall mysql` and `npm install mysql2` then just import it normally `const mysql = require('mysql2')`

Comment: I installed MySQL on the mysql.com website. Not sure if that would be effecting this or not

Comment: what? i don't understand the problem. I think we all install mysql from that site though. `npm uninstall` will uninstall the package in your project, not the program.

Comment: I'll try this method and see how it goes. Will I have to tweak my code at all?

Comment: no, we just simply change the package/tool that asists us in connecting to mysql server

Comment: I tried this and got '  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Applications/ProjectVirtual/ProjectVirtual/server.js' ]'

Comment: that's so strange. Can you post the `dependencies` part in your package.json? you might not have the `mysql` package installed.

Comment: Yeah I'll copy and paste the package.json right below my source code in my post

Comment: I pasted package.json, so you should be able to see the package in the dependency

Comment: ok now `mysql2` package is installed, you can continue with the `const mysql = require('mysql2')` then run the express server

Comment: if it doesn't work i'll copy your code and try to make it run on my pc then push the code on github.

Comment: Oh damn, that's what I forgot to add. Thanks, this should work

Comment: Not sure if there's anything wrong with my code, I don't believe there is. This is a deeper problem with my OS or something. I closed out VSC and will open again.

Comment: sorry i forgot one change: the "name" in the createConnection should be changed to "user". so it's user:"root" now.

Comment: So like this ''' const mysqlconn = mysql2.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1:3306',
    user: 'root',
    name: 'user',
    password: 'cbcxc$57&hdd^',
    database: 'MyDatabase',
});'''

Comment: Yes, but make sure that your password is right and your database already existed. Please double check it, they are the final pieces of this puzzle.

Comment: Say I were to omit the password and db name, would this change anything?

Comment: You mentioned a package for mysql. Will this help?

Comment: you don't know about npm package yet? they are tools that help you build an app in nodejs. `mysql` package helps express app to connect to mysql server. Without any of username/ password/ host/ database name you won't be able to connect at all.

Comment: I do, but mentioned some other mysql tool to help with this specific issue

Comment: *You mentioned. Sorry

Comment: no, `mysql` package is pretty old by now, i simply want to use the latest tool. Still, i copied your code and use the old `mysql` package and got it running. Everything you've done is ok now, just need the right password and database name.

Comment: The thing is, it never asked me for these two things when I installed mysql

Comment: I knew the code was fine, this is pretty simple stuff. No valid reason why it shouldn't be connecting

Comment: What other messaging platform do you use again? I was able to screenshot the popup message

Comment: I can send it now

Comment: Anyway here is another snippet of the error in the cmd, 'Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: name. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection
Listening on port 3060..'

Comment: TypeORM is the one you mentioned

Comment: I just want to apologize if I'm bugging you, I'm sure you got other things going on. I just can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: wait i didn't read your previous reply thoroughly, you should remove the "name". it's `user:"root"` is needed, not `name: "something"`. It's simply a warning that about an unrecognized setting, the full code of the connection would be `const mysqlconn = mysql2.createConnection({ host: '127.0.0.1:3306', user: 'root',password: 'cbcxc$57&hdd^', database: 'MyDatabase', });` . Also for the pop up it's just nodejs needs to be allowed to make connection, i tried to copy your code and got the pop up too.

Comment: message me on discord if you are able to, my username is "freegwid", i'll work around it. When you install mysql server there would be a part that you need to create an username and password, which is what you need in the code to connect.

Comment: You just need to log in via system command line (with username and password) then create a database with raw query. The easier way is install MySQL workbench to log in/ display those info with those any command.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't give me the choice of creating a username or password in the cmd. I never seen that. I'll try and connect with you on Discord

Comment: Yeah perhaps I should try workbench

Comment: Do you know the cmd line for installing workbench? I know it starts with npm install. I sent you a request

Comment: You need to download workbench from their [official website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), not npm. npm is for package, not an actual app. Let's continue on discord.